# Detect memory leak automatically

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory-leaks

I wrote a java script web page, and i want to detect automatically parts of codes that cause a memory leak in that page( for example creating timer objects and not releasing them).
i want to do it automatically because when i leave the browser open (with this page) it crashes only after two days.
I am familiar with the Chrome dev tool that allows taking snapshots and comparing them.
However, it requires taking snapshots and making the comparison manually.
I was wondering, is it possible to programmatically detect memory leaks without the need for a manual intervention?